# How to identify the specific cell hovered over in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, cell

I have put a picture at the end of all datagridview rows to delete row when pressed.
[image]
I want to change color of that picture on specific cell mouseover (Inorder to indicate it is an interactive button to the user).

However in all solutions I found full DGV mouseover is explianed.
What I need: Learn how to find the **specific cell hovered over** during cell mouseover.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms? WPF? ASP? ...?? __Always__ tag your question accordingly! - For winforms: Have a look at [DataGridView.Hittest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.hittest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)! - Also note that MouseHover will only fire once per MouseEnter. So you may need a little more logic or go directly for the MouseMove.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is WindowsForms:

```
//when mouse is over cell
    private void dataGridView1_CellMouseMove(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex >= 0)
        {
            dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.Black;
        }
    }
//when mouse is leaving cell
    private void dataGridView1_CellMouseLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex >= 0)
        {
            dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.White;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Old question, and @titol's answer is good, but I don't like to use the event `CellMouseMove` for this (it triggers too often).

I suggest capturing when the mouse enter with `CellMouseEnter` and, of course, `CellMouseLeave`. Like this:

```
    void dataGridView1_CellMouseEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
        if (e.RowIndex < 0 || e.ColumnIndex < 0) return;
        var gv = sender as DataGridView;
        var column = gv.Columns[e.ColumnIndex];
        if (myLogicToCheckIfIsTrashButtonColumn(column)) {
            gv[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.Black;
            gv.InvalidateCell(gv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex]);
        }
    }

    void dataGridView1_CellMouseLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
        if (e.RowIndex < 0 || e.ColumnIndex < 0) return;
        var gv = sender as DataGridView;
        var column = gv.Columns[e.ColumnIndex];
        if (myLogicToCheckIfIsTrashButtonColumn(column)) {
            gv[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.White;
            gv.InvalidateCell(gv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex]);
        }
    }
```